# Can not start android emulator from command line

Tags: android, command-line, android-emulator

Windows 7, Android Studio 2.3

I has 3 emulators. And all success start from Android Studio.

But I want to start them from command line.
So my steps (from command lines):

1. **emulator -list-avds**

Success show all my emulators:

1. Nexus_3_7_API_17_ver_4_2_1
2. Nexus_3_7_hdpi_API_24_7_0
3. Nexus_5_96_xxhdpi_API_24_7_0

So I want to start one of them:

**emulator -avd Nexus_3_7_API_17_ver_4_2_1**

But I get error:

```
[8648]:ERROR:./android/qt/qt_setup.cpp:28:Qt library not found at ..\emulator\lib64\qt\lib
Could not launch '..\emulator/qemu/windows-x86_64/qemu-system-i386.exe': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I had the exact same issue and I am using a workaround. Let me explain:

There is a 'bug' in the emulator: it is not able to find the relative path

```
..\emulator\lib64\qt\lib
```

Incredibly awesome since this is so simple to fix... whatever.

Just cd to c:\path\to\your\android-sdks\emulator, typically something like

```
cd c:\Users\<YOUR_USER_NAME>\android-sdks\emulator
```

then, **in this directory**, run any emulator command you want, for instance your command:

```
emulator.exe -avd Nexus_3_7_API_17_ver_4_2_1
```

in your teminal this will look like this:

```
c:\Users\<YOUR_USER_NAME>\android-sdks\emulator> emulator.exe -avd Nexus_3_7_API_17_ver_4_2_1
```

and it will work.

Comment: on Windows 10, working with .\ before emulator.exe as .\emulator.exe -avd Nexus_3_7_API_17_ver_4_2_1

Answer (score 13):

Adding emulator path in Environmental Variables solved my problem. Now, I can run emulator command from anywhere.

You can achieve this by following these steps:

1. Open 'Advanced System Settings'.
2. Click 'Environmental Variables'.
3. Add the following to Path variables in both boxes:

   `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator`
4. Restart Command Prompt.

> Note: Your path could be different than the one mentioned above. If
>   this is the case, then you have to search for your emulator path.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Command Prompt
2. go to path of your emulator for ex:

`$ cd c:\sdk\tools`

3. run emulator :

`$ emulator -avd Nexus_3_7_API_17_ver_4_2_1`

Comment: Is it possible from any place to run emulator? Without cd c:\sdk\tools

Comment: emulator  dependent on libraries in that folder in linux you can use this by add this function  to ~/.profile (or ~/.bashrc) :
function emulator { cd "$(dirname "$(which emulator)")" && ./emulator "$@"; }

Comment: I was able to make it work by adding the following to my bashhrc:
"function emulator {
  cd '/Users/locus/Library/Android/sdk/emulator'
  ./emulator "$@"
}"

Answer (score 1):

For Mac user, similar to Pascal's answer, in Terminal type:

```
cd /Users/myname/Library/Android/sdk/tools
./emulator -adv mydevicename
```

For other mac users below might be what's needed.

```
cd ~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator
./emulator -avd Nexus_S_API_31 -change-locale fr-CA
```

my error when executing the followings:

```
emulator -avd Pixel_2_API_28

[4809612736]:ERROR:android/android-emu/android/qt/qt_setup.cpp:28:Qt library not found at ../emulator/lib64/qt/lib
Could not launch '/Users/myname/.android/../emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

i think the error due to ,u didn't specified exact location so do like this

- Open Command Prompt 
  write this 
  emulator -avd avd_name [ {-option [value]} … ]

> /Users/janedoe/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator -avd Nexus_3_7_API_17_ver_4_2_1 -netdelay none -netspeed full

Comment: Of cause I need to specify the full path. But I don't want to do this every time.  I want to start emulator from ANY place without full  path.

Comment: what do u mean of "from any place" ?

Comment: please be specific

Comment: e.g. start emulator when I'm in folder "C:\temp" , or "D:\dev\myProject\"

Comment: alter direcotry

Comment: I don't want to start emulator like this: "c:\Program Files\android-sdk-windows\emulator -avd Nexus_3_7_API_17_ver_4_2_1".   I want to start emulator like this:  "emulator -avd Nexus_3_7_API_17_ver_4_2_1"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142751/discussion-between-abubakar-and-alexei).

Answer (score 0):

Open command prompt and enter this path:

cd c:\Users\userName\android-sdks\emulator

after this:

emulator -avd avd_name

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your ~/.bashhrc or ~/.zshrc, remembering to update the username:

```
function emulator {
  cd '/Users/locus/Library/Android/sdk/emulator'
  ./emulator "$@"
}
```

Afterwards do to reload the changes:

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

Then, verify it works by running:

```
emulator -list-avds
```