# Android Studio API 29 and above emulators crash immediately

Tags: android, api, android-studio, crash, emulation

I'm using the latest version of Android Studio as of this writing, which is 4.0.1.
I'm running on Windows 10 pro, Intel Core i7-6600U with 16 GB of RAM.

When I try to run an emulator using either API 29 or API 30, it crashes immediately.  This is the only relevant message I get:
2:26 PM Emulator: C:\Users\usrname\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe: error while loading state for instance 0x0 of device 'goldfish_pipe'

2:26 PM Emulator: deleteSnapshot: for default_boot

Nothing at all in the logcat.

If I run an emulator using API 28 or older, it works fine.

Update: with the help of others I tried running it from the command line.  Here's what it said:

Failed to open /qemu.conf, err: 2
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
C:\Users\mkolta\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe: error while loading state for instance 0x0 of device 'goldfish_pipe'
deleteSnapshot: for default_boot
VCPU shutdown request
VCPU shutdown request
emulator: Saving state on exit with session uptime 97 ms
VCPU shutdown request

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: try starting emulator from the command line and see if it returns more error messages there

Comment: I am not able to start the emulator from the command line and would appreciate some assistance. From the terminal, I went to C:\Users\username\.android\avd and from there I can do a dir to see the list of emulator.  Then I try the emulator -list-avds command and I get an error message: 'emulator' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.   I realize this is not the location as stated in the directions I've read, but that location doesn't exist on my system: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43627750/can-not-start-android-emulator-from-command-line

Comment: navigate to your AndroidSDK installation directory, emulator.exe is inside emulator folder. Try running command from there.

Comment: Did you find a solution?  I'm experiencing the exact same issue.  API version 28 and lower launches fine, version 29 and higher immediately crashes.

Comment: No solution yet.  I tried everything that was suggested here, at least the ones that I understood, and there was no change.  I was not able to "update key-tool" as Bhargav suggested below because I do not know how and wasn't able to find information about that.  If you know how, please share.

Answer (score 1):

Just update Haxm, you can download from:

[GitHub HAXM](https://github.com/intel/haxm/releases)

Comment: spent two hours on this and tried many things from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36841461/error-android-emulator-gets-killed) and simply updating haxm from 7.6.5 to 7.6.6 fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to update key-tool and install all SDK requirements

Comment: I updated the JDK from version 11 to the latest version (14).  I updated the SDK to the latest version, which I got from here https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools.  I simply replaced my existing SDK files with these that I just downloaded.  I'm still getting the same behavior.  I'm not exactly sure how to "update key-tool".  Can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

just do this two steps:

1. upgrade Haxm to last version (current is: 7.5.6)
2. enable Hyper-v