# How to configure proxy in emulators in new versions of Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, ide

### Problem Description

I need to configure the proxy manually in my emulator through Android Studio. From the [official Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking.html?authuser=1#proxy), it is suggested that this change can be made in the "settings" tab of the emulator's extended controls. The problem is that it seems to me that this documentation is outdated, as this setting is no longer displayed in the "settings" tab of the Android Studio emulators' extended controls.

#### Documentation

[image: with proxy]

#### My Android Studio

[image: without proxy]

### My version of Android Studio

```
Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1
Build #AI-211.7628.21.2111.8092744, built on January 19, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.11+9-b60-7590822 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by Oracle Corporation
Windows 10 10.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 1280M
Cores: 8
Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
Non-Bundled Plugins: com.wakatime.intellij.plugin (13.1.10), wu.seal.tool.jsontokotlin (3.7.2), org.jetbrains.kotlin (211-1.6.10-release-923-AS7442.40), com.developerphil.adbidea (1.6.4), org.jetbrains.compose.desktop.ide (1.0.0), ru.adelf.idea.dotenv (2021.2), org.intellij.plugins.markdown (211.7142.37)
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can open old emulator version by unchecking setting here[image]

If you struggle to close your old emulator, try killing qemu... process

Answer (score 8):

You can go to setup proxy in Android Studio itself.

1. Configure Proxy in the Preferences window
   [image: Preferences window]

   1. Go to *Preferences window* (Mac: cmd+, shortcut).
   2. Click *Appearance & Behavior* on the left panel
   3. Click *System Settings* on the left panel
   4. Click *HTTTP Proxy* on the left panel
   5. Setup your preferred proxy settings
   6. Confirm by clicking *OK*
2. You need to **restart emulator** to apply your changes

*The downside of the solution is that the proxy is also applied to Android Studio itself. So traffic from Android Studio goes through the proxy.*

Comment: The settings from Android Studio are not used in the emulator - at least not on my machine. Settings in AS are working perfectly fine, still the Android Emulator has no Internet access. Strange.

Answer (score 4):

After a while trying to find solutions to this problem, I saw that an **emulator running outside android studio provides these options**. To run a standalone Android Studio emulator see the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline) or simply enter the command:

```
emulator -avd <avd_name>
```

In my case I'm using an avd named `PIXEL 4 API 30`, so the command will be `emulator -avd PIXEL_4_API_30`. If you are on Windows you may have problems running this command so I suggest you see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43627750/can-not-start-android-emulator-from-command-line).

### Edit

The solution proposed by @Inliner also solves this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the proxy in the emulator wifi settings. Click on internet settings, select androidWifi. Click on the edit icon then add your proxy there.

[image: Android wifi settings]

[image: Edit network settings]

[image: Proxy setup]